# Implement constructors with variables from another class?

Tags: java

I'm a java beginner and would like some help implementing my constructors

for example

```
public Class WidthLenth {
private double width;
private double length;

public WidthLength(double width, double length) {
this.width = width;
this.length = length;
}

public double getWidth() {
return width;
}

public double getLength() {
return length;
}
```

and in another class

```
public Class Rectangle {
private WidthLength widthLength <-- there is a uni-directional relationship here
private String color
```

I need to the constructor to be in this format

```
public Rectangle(double width, double length, String color) {
}
```

So the method

```
public getWidthLenth() {
}
```

would work.

how would I implement this constructor?

Answer (score 0):

You just create a new object of `WidthLength` in the constructor.

```
public Rectangle(double width, double length, String col)
{
    widthLength = new WidthLength(width, length);
    color = col;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public Rectangle(double width, double length, String color) {
    this.widthLength = new WidthLength(width, length);
    this.color = color;
}

public WidthLength getWidthLength() {
    return this.widthLength;
}
```